# DIV over flash object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, firefox

I put absolutely positioned DIV over the page which contains flash object. The div has high z-index and intercepts click event. 
The purpose is to get click in the div when the flash object is clicked.

```
<html>
<head>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var htmlHeight = $(html).height() + 'px';
        var htmlWidth = $(html).width() + 'px';
        var fgDiv = $('body').append('<div>');
            fgDiv.css("position": "absolute");
            fgDiv.css("top", 0); 
            fgDiv.css("left", 0);
            fgDiv.css("width", htmlWidth);
            fgDiv.css("height", htmlHeight);
            fgDiv.css("z-index", 99999);
            fgDiv.on('click', function() {
                alert("Hello, World!");
            });
    });
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello, World!</div>
    <div><object width="400" height="50" data="img/car.swf"></object></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution perfectly works in MS Windows and Linux Chrome but **not on Windows / Linux Firefox.**

What can be a reason?

Comment: Flash Player is different between browsers so what do you think about OSs ?! Try to use an `opaque` or `transparent` `wmode` for your SWF object ...

Comment: Turned out that on Firefox in Windows it does not work, too. So, the "problem" is in Firefox. The swf object is not mine.

Comment: `wmode` is an `<object>`'s property ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create that div to cover just the SWF object without covering all the content of your HTML page, and don't forget to set the `wmode` of your SWF object.

**HTML :**

```
<div id='swf_container' style='position: relative;'>
    <object id='swf_object' width='400' height='50' data='swf.swf' wmode='opaque'></object>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var height = $('#swf_object').height() + 'px',
        width = $('#swf_object').width() + 'px';

    var div = $('<div style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0; width:'+width+'; height: '+height+'; z-index: 99999;"></div>')
        .on('click', function(){
            alert('Hello, World!');
        });

    $('#swf_container').append(div);

});
```

I don't have Linux right now to test this code but it is working fine in Windows (Firefox, Chrome).

Hope that can help.